# Check if enum exists in Java

Tags: java, string, enums, compare

Is there anyway to check if an enum exists by comparing it to a given string? I can't seem to find any such function. I could just try to use the `valueOf` method and catch an exception but I'v been taught that catching runtime exceptions is not good practice. Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: I really don't understand the idea behind emum valueOf throwing an exception... it does not make any sense. It would be a lot more practical in every aspect if it would just return NULL.

Comment: @marcolopes: One reason would be wanting to cover every possible cases with Enum. If an Enum isn't found, it means the dev should be notified as soon as possible that there's a missing case. It shouldn't let the program throw a NullPointerError somewhere else, later in the code.

Comment: @EricDuminil a null result would be simpler... that's what i do! I basically don't use valueOf on my code, and write a new method inside the enum get(value) that catches the exception...

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I don't think there's a built-in way to do it without catching exceptions. You could instead use something like this:

```
public static MyEnum asMyEnum(String str) {
    for (MyEnum me : MyEnum.values()) {
        if (me.name().equalsIgnoreCase(str))
            return me;
    }
    return null;
}
```

**Edit:** As Jon Skeet notes, `values()` works by cloning a private backing array every time it is called. If performance is critical, you may want to call `values()` only once, cache the array, and iterate through that.

Also, if your enum has a huge number of values, Jon Skeet's map alternative is likely to perform better than any array iteration.

Answer (score 78):

If I need to do this, I sometimes build a `Set<String>` of the names, or even my own `Map<String,MyEnum>` - then you can just check that.

A couple of points worth noting:

- Populate any such static collection in a static initializer. *Don't* use a variable initializer and then rely on it having been executed when the enum constructor runs - it won't have been! (The enum constructors are the first things to be executed, before the static initializer.)
- Try to avoid using `values()` frequently - it has to create and populate a new array each time. To iterate over all elements, use [`EnumSet.allOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html#allOf-java.lang.Class-) which is much more efficient for enums without a large number of elements.

Sample code:

```
import java.util.*;

enum SampleEnum {
    Foo,
    Bar;

    private static final Map<String, SampleEnum> nameToValueMap =
        new HashMap<String, SampleEnum>();
    
    static {
        for (SampleEnum value : EnumSet.allOf(SampleEnum.class)) {
            nameToValueMap.put(value.name(), value);
        }
    }
    
    public static SampleEnum forName(String name) {
        return nameToValueMap.get(name);
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String [] args)
        throws Exception { // Just for simplicity!
        System.out.println(SampleEnum.forName("Foo"));
        System.out.println(SampleEnum.forName("Bar"));
        System.out.println(SampleEnum.forName("Baz"));
    }
}
```

Of course, if you only have a few names this is probably overkill - an O(n) solution often wins over an O(1) solution when n is small enough. Here's another approach:

```
import java.util.*;

enum SampleEnum {
    Foo,
    Bar;

    // We know we'll never mutate this, so we can keep
    // a local copy.
    private static final SampleEnum[] copyOfValues = values();
    
    public static SampleEnum forName(String name) {
        for (SampleEnum value : copyOfValues) {
            if (value.name().equals(name)) {
                return value;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String [] args)
        throws Exception { // Just for simplicity!
        System.out.println(SampleEnum.forName("Foo"));
        System.out.println(SampleEnum.forName("Bar"));
        System.out.println(SampleEnum.forName("Baz"));
    }
}
```

Comment: `values()` creates and populates a new array? I don't remember hearing that before, but presumably you have a source?

Comment: Well it returns an array... and it can't protect you from mutating that array... and it wouldn't subsequent callers to be hampered by that. Other than that, look at the JRE sources :)

Comment: It's not in the JRE sources, that's why I asked. But I hadn't thought of the mutation aspect; you're probably right, then.

Comment: Oops, sorry - yes, just checked myself. Decompile an enum then :) It uses clone() which may be pretty quick, but not as quick as not having to do it at all...

Comment: Ah, the question of how `values()` works was asked and answered within the last day: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163076/how-is-values-implemented-for-java-6-enums/1163121#1163121.

Comment: I bet the cost of clone is minimal to checking through the array (particularly if the target `String` is not interned.)

Comment: Are there any guidelines as to what "size" enums benefit from the Map-based approach vs. the array/loop approach? (I'm not looking for hard/fast rules, just a general ballpark of when to think about doing one way vs. the other)

Comment: @cdeszaq: I suspect it could vary significantly between JVMs and situations. If it's something you're concerned may be significant in your app, I suggest you do performance tests. Sorry not to be able to be more helpful :(

Answer (score 53):

One of my favorite lib: Apache Commons.

The [EnumUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/EnumUtils.html) can do that easily.

Following an example to validate an Enum with that library:

```
public enum MyEnum {
    DIV("div"), DEPT("dept"), CLASS("class");

    private final String val;

    MyEnum(String val) {
    this.val = val;
    }

    public String getVal() {
    return val;
    }
}


MyEnum strTypeEnum = null;

// test if String str is compatible with the enum 
// e.g. if you pass str = "div", it will return false. If you pass "DIV", it will return true.
if( EnumUtils.isValidEnum(MyEnum.class, str) ){
    strTypeEnum = MyEnum.valueOf(str);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. In fact it is minimal because using libs others did, is often the best solution than re-coding it yourself. If you do it yourself you are arriving to the exact same solution ("Reinventing the wheel") or you miss something important and it behave worst (then in that case you "Reinventing the square wheel")

Comment: Yes exactly. Apache Commons is full kitchen; worth only when you get full or maximum benefit from it :) Square Wheel :P

Comment: In my opinion, Apache Commons must be a "common basis dependencies" to add in any Java projects ;)

Comment: unfortunately i am  using commons-lang-2.6.jar i didnt find EnumUtils.isValidEnum what is the next possible thing ?

Comment: @DasariVinodh perhaps it's time to migrate your dependencies?

Comment: This implementation does try catch of valueOf() internally which is exactly what the OP is trying to avoid. I don't know how this is such an upvoted answer.

Comment: @harogaston: there is a difference between catching exceptions yourself or delegate it to a library. The OP did not mention to forbid the exception handling at all. The library is supposed to be optimised and under control. At least this make your code cleaner and not managing the exception yourself (and prone to potential errors, that's the way I understood the question). The implementation of the lib can use any techniques and even it can change in the time, your code will not be different.

Comment: @рüффп OP clearly says "but I've been taught that catching runtime exceptions is not good practice" That implementation does exactly that. Plus there is no way to "optimize" the catching of an exception unless you tweak the JVM itself. So this remains not the correct answer.

Comment: Catching runtime exception is not always a bad practice, this should be done with care on specific exceptions. Most of the most used frameworks (e.g. Camel, Spring, and so on) does that and programmers continue to use them without thinking if it's a good practice or not. Catching the Throwable or the root Exception is definitively not a good practice but I have some cases where the 3rd party throws that kind of exception and I have no choice than catching the class Exception in my code. Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32545382/628006).

Answer (score 6):

I don't know why anyone told you that catching runtime exceptions was bad.

Use `valueOf` and catching `IllegalArgumentException` is fine for converting/checking a string to an enum.

Comment: No it's not, IMO. That's testing a non-exceptional situation via exceptions - using them for flow control in a normal, non-error condition. That's a very poor use of exceptions IMO, and one which can have a significant performance impact. Exceptions are fine in terms of performance normally, because they shouldn't happen - but when you use them for non-error conditions, then code which *looks* like it should run quickly can get bogged down.

Comment: Funny thing - based on this opinion (which I will normally share as well), I decided to use Apache Commons `EnumUtils.isValidEnum` way to have it as "clean" possible. And guess how `EnumUtils.isValidEnum` is implemented - catching `IllegalArgumentException` of course :-)

Comment: Well, if the string you're testing for is supplied by the user, than it is an expected situation to get an IllegalArgumentException, right?
Honestly I'm a bit surprised there isn't a method in Enum for this use case.

Comment: @JonSkeet I think you are wrong. Here it s not about flow control, lets take an API, often we will maybe wait string value from an api ( often define by the application and theorically have 100% chance to exist, lets talk about an order "shipped" "pending" "cancelled" ), so if my api accept only 3 values as enum for exemple, and we provide a wrong one, it should raise an exception, which will probably raise a bad request response.

Comment: @amdev: It's *very easy* for you to detect that and throw an exception in your own code, if that's what you want. It's far uglier for *other* use cases to have to swallow an exception when the value isn't present. Do you believe `map.get` should throw an exception if the key isn't present, too? It would potentially be cleaner to have two separate methods - one throwing and one not - but while there's only a single method, I think it 's much cleaner for it *not* to throw.

Comment: @amdev leaving style considerations aside, the "problem" with exceptions is that the JVM has to prepare a whole stack trace for you, and it takes some time. If you expect a lot of bad requests, maybe it is worth implementing some O(1) verification method in order to avoid the overhead caused by exceptions.

Comment: Of course an exception is exceptionnal and in my scenario the app send the `order status` and theorically the enum will always match the string. Everything depends of the use case, if you never except that the enum will not match the string so it's exceptionnal and it should raise an exception. If it's a common case yes you should probably just test that your string is correct before to try to convert it, anyway in this scenario, if you test your string before to call valueOf, it still very exceptional that the enum will not match.

Answer (score 6):

Based on Jon Skeet answer i've made a class that permits to do it easily at work:

```
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap;
import com.google.common.collect.Maps;

import java.util.EnumSet;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * <p>
 * This permits to easily implement a failsafe implementation of the enums's valueOf
 * Better use it inside the enum so that only one of this object instance exist for each enum...
 * (a cache could solve this if needed)
 * </p>
 *
 * <p>
 * Basic usage exemple on an enum class called MyEnum:
 *
 *   private static final FailSafeValueOf<MyEnum> FAIL_SAFE = FailSafeValueOf.create(MyEnum.class);
 *   public static MyEnum failSafeValueOf(String enumName) {
 *       return FAIL_SAFE.valueOf(enumName);
 *   }
 *
 * </p>
 *
 * <p>
 * You can also use it outside of the enum this way:
 *   FailSafeValueOf.create(MyEnum.class).valueOf("EnumName");
 * </p>
 *
 * @author Sebastien Lorber <i>(lorber.sebastien@gmail.com)</i>
 */
public class FailSafeValueOf<T extends Enum<T>> {

    private final Map<String,T> nameToEnumMap;

    private FailSafeValueOf(Class<T> enumClass) {
        Map<String,T> map = Maps.newHashMap();
        for ( T value : EnumSet.allOf(enumClass)) {
            map.put( value.name() , value);
        }
        nameToEnumMap = ImmutableMap.copyOf(map);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the value of the given enum element
     * If the 
     * @param enumName
     * @return
     */
    public T valueOf(String enumName) {
        return nameToEnumMap.get(enumName);
    }

    public static <U extends Enum<U>> FailSafeValueOf<U> create(Class<U> enumClass) {
        return new FailSafeValueOf<U>(enumClass);
    }

}
```

And the unit test:

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import static org.testng.Assert.*;


/**
 * @author Sebastien Lorber <i>(lorber.sebastien@gmail.com)</i>
 */
public class FailSafeValueOfTest {

    private enum MyEnum {
        TOTO,
        TATA,
        ;

        private static final FailSafeValueOf<MyEnum> FAIL_SAFE = FailSafeValueOf.create(MyEnum.class);
        public static MyEnum failSafeValueOf(String enumName) {
            return FAIL_SAFE.valueOf(enumName);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testInEnum() {
        assertNotNull( MyEnum.failSafeValueOf("TOTO") );
        assertNotNull( MyEnum.failSafeValueOf("TATA") );
        assertNull( MyEnum.failSafeValueOf("TITI") );
    }

    @Test
    public void testInApp() {
        assertNotNull( FailSafeValueOf.create(MyEnum.class).valueOf("TOTO") );
        assertNotNull( FailSafeValueOf.create(MyEnum.class).valueOf("TATA") );
        assertNull( FailSafeValueOf.create(MyEnum.class).valueOf("TITI") );
    }

}
```

Notice that i used Guava to make an ImmutableMap but actually you could use a normal map i think since the map is never returned...

Answer (score 4):

Most of the answers suggest either using a loop with equals to check if the enum exists or using try/catch with enum.valueOf(). I wanted to know which method is faster and tried it. I am not very good at benchmarking, so please correct me if I made any mistakes.

Heres the code of my main class:

```
    package enumtest;

public class TestMain {

    static long timeCatch, timeIterate;
    static String checkFor;
    static int corrects;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        timeCatch = 0;
        timeIterate = 0;
        TestingEnum[] enumVals = TestingEnum.values();
        String[] testingStrings = new String[enumVals.length * 5];
        for (int j = 0; j < 10000; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < testingStrings.length; i++) {
                if (i % 5 == 0) {
                    testingStrings[i] = enumVals[i / 5].toString();
                } else {
                    testingStrings[i] = "DOES_NOT_EXIST" + i;
                }
            }

            for (String s : testingStrings) {
                checkFor = s;
                if (tryCatch()) {
                    ++corrects;
                }
                if (iterate()) {
                    ++corrects;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(timeCatch / 1000 + "us for try catch");
        System.out.println(timeIterate / 1000 + "us for iterate");
        System.out.println(corrects);
    }

    static boolean tryCatch() {
        long timeStart, timeEnd;
        timeStart = System.nanoTime();
        try {
            TestingEnum.valueOf(checkFor);
            return true;
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            return false;
        } finally {
            timeEnd = System.nanoTime();
            timeCatch += timeEnd - timeStart;
        }

    }

    static boolean iterate() {
        long timeStart, timeEnd;
        timeStart = System.nanoTime();
        TestingEnum[] values = TestingEnum.values();
        for (TestingEnum v : values) {
            if (v.toString().equals(checkFor)) {
                timeEnd = System.nanoTime();
                timeIterate += timeEnd - timeStart;
                return true;
            }
        }
        timeEnd = System.nanoTime();
        timeIterate += timeEnd - timeStart;
        return false;
    }
}
```

This means, each methods run 50000 times the lenght of the enum
I ran this test multiple times, with 10, 20, 50 and 100 enum constants.
Here are the results:

- 10: try/catch: 760ms | iteration: 62ms
- 20: try/catch: 1671ms | iteration: 177ms
- 50: try/catch: 3113ms | iteration: 488ms
- 100: try/catch: 6834ms | iteration: 1760ms

These results were not exact. When executing it again, there is up to 10% difference in the results, but they are enough to show, that the try/catch method is far less efficient, especially with small enums.

Answer (score 4):

Since Java 8, we could use [streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) instead of for loops. Also, it might be apropriate to return an [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) if the enum does not have an instance with such a name.

I have come up with the following three alternatives on how to look up an enum:

```
private enum Test {
    TEST1, TEST2;

    public Test fromNameOrThrowException(String name) {
        return Arrays.stream(values())
                .filter(e -> e.name().equals(name))
                .findFirst()
                .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("No enum with name " + name));
    }

    public Test fromNameOrNull(String name) {
        return Arrays.stream(values()).filter(e -> e.name().equals(name)).findFirst().orElse(null);
    }

    public Optional<Test> fromName(String name) {
        return Arrays.stream(values()).filter(e -> e.name().equals(name)).findFirst();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use `valueOf()` method.

If the value doesn't exist, it throws `IllegalArgumentException` and you can `catch` it like that:

```
boolean isSettingCodeValid = true;
try {
    SettingCode.valueOf(settingCode.toUpperCase());
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    // throw custom exception or change the isSettingCodeValid value
    isSettingCodeValid = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Guava and do something like this:

```
// This method returns enum for a given string if it exists, otherwise it returns default enum.
private MyEnum getMyEnum(String enumName) {
  // It is better to return default instance of enum instead of null
  return hasMyEnum(enumName) ? MyEnum.valueOf(enumName) : MyEnum.DEFAULT;
}

// This method checks that enum for a given string exists.
private boolean hasMyEnum(String enumName) {
  return Iterables.any(Arrays.asList(MyEnum.values()), new Predicate<MyEnum>() {
    public boolean apply(MyEnum myEnum) {
      return myEnum.name().equals(enumName);
    }
  }); 
}
```

In second method I use guava ([Google Guava](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Guava)) library which provides very useful **Iterables** class. Using the **Iterables.any()** method we can check if a given value exists in a list object. This method needs two parameters: a list and **Predicate** object. First I used **Arrays.asList()** method to create a list with all enums. After that I created new **Predicate** object which is used to check if a given element (enum in our case) satisfies the condition in **apply** method. If that happens, method **Iterables.any()** returns true value.

Answer (score 1):

Using java 8, you can do something like the below to check if it is valid.

```
Stream.of(MyEnum.values())
        .map(MyEnum::name)
        .collect(Collectors.toList()).contains(<STRING_YOU_WANT_TO_VALIDATE>)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I use to check if an enum constant with given name exists:

```java
java.util.Arrays.stream(E.values()).map(E::name).toList().contains("");
```

(Suppose your enum is called E.) Here inside "" you should put a name of an enum constant for which you wish to check if it is defined in the enum or not.
This is certainly not the best possible solution since it converts an array into Stream and then again into List, but is nice and short and it works fine for me.

As other people mentioned, since you asked this question in 2009., this will not work in your case (unless you migrated to a newer version of Java) since in 2009. Java did not support features used in this answer. But I am posting anyway in case someone with newer version of Java wants to do this.