# Is it useless to throw an exception in a catch block?

Tags: java, exception

I am trying to figure out what is the best way to handle exceptions in java.
Is it a good idea to throw RunTimeException inside a catch block or it is useless?

```
public final void clickOnElement(MobileElement mobileElement, int secondsToWait) {
    try {
        abstractPlatform.clickOnElement(mobileElement,secondsToWait);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException("Wasn't able to click on element " + mobileElement);
    }
}
```

Comment: Define _useless_.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best practice for Java exception handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32545270/best-practice-for-java-exception-handling)

Comment: You're catching one exception, just to make the application stop by throwing another one. In my eyes this is pretty useless yes.

Comment: In technical point of view for given code fragment, it will throw an exception if catch is executed. try-catch basically for handle exceptions. So base on your requirement it should be decided by yourself. What if you need to throw an customized exception instead of real exception. So decided by you either it's worth or not.

Comment: It all depends on what you want to do if the exception fires.  In your example, your catching all exceptions, and assuming that they're all a "NoSuchElementException".

Comment: if the exception will be thrown in a case of an error without me explicitly throwing it I call it useless. So basically my question is, if I don't explicitly throw an exception, will the application stop in a case of an error regarding viability of an element for example?

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes one indeed wants a RuntimeException instead of a checked exception.

```
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new NoSuchElementException("Wasn't able to click on element " + mobileElement, e);
}
```

I would specify the exact exceptions, like `IOException|SQLException`, and add it as cause to the rethrow.

A recent use-case are *lambdas* that are in a context (streams) where checked exceptions are not allowed.

Or simply to add *additional info* that might help pinpoint the error, like file name or SQL statement & parameters.

Especially IllegalArgumentException and IllegalStateException can be more informative than other exceptions.

Comment: I don't think lambdas are a recent use case, they were introduced in Java 8, and that one is almost at the end of life

Comment: Or you may need to do some cleanup and then rethrow.

Comment: @Ferrybig in the grand scheme of Java, yeah, lambdas are a pretty recent development. Especially if you consider that many are still running java 7.

Comment: upvoted. but i would add, if clickOnElement is not throwing any checked exceptions then this should catch RuntimeException instead of Exception.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca yeah, cleanup & rethrow also reminds me of try-with-resources.

Comment: @NathanHughes indeed. Though when to catch in what amplexity is not answered with my question.

Answer (score 0):

No its not useless, I do this a lot in code I write I would rather see my own custom exception with a message about the error, since you are handling where it is caught in most of those cases you will know why it has thrown, so I much prefer to see an exception with a detailed message about the exact issue instead of a generic exception been thrown and just seeing an error message in the console, an example of something useless would be

```
try {
    abstractPlatform.clickOnElement(mobileElement,secondsToWait);
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw e;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It may or may not be useless, totally depends on how we use it. I have used it in a way so that I can maintain logs for exceptions.

```
public final void clickOnElement(MobileElement mobileElement, int secondsToWait) 
{
  try 
  {
    abstractPlatform.clickOnElement(mobileElement,secondsToWait);
  } 
  catch (Exception e) 
  {
    logError(this, "clickOnElement()", "Wasn't able to click on element"+mobileElement);
    throw new NoSuchElementException("Wasn't able to click on element " + mobileElement);
  }
}
```

Now in this case I have created a method that logged exception for that particular method and by looking at the logs I might be able to figure out the cause of exception. But lets assume that this piece of code is being used in an API.

And as a API designer I want to return some specific status code instead of showing exception message send by the tomcat/framework. In that case we can throw the exception in catch and that exception can be held in some parent method or by the framework itself if there is some mechanism in place for that.

So its all upto how we use it.

Comment: I agree with you, this is all depends upon your implementation, if you want to implement elastic search or logging module then you have to throw exception in catch block