# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum BusinessCustomersStatus.4d29e059cf

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, enums, spring-data-jpa

I want to create a search Specification using ENUM values:

Search ENUM:

```
public enum BusinessCustomersStatus {
    A("active"),
    O("onboarding"),
    N("not_verified"),
    V("verified"),
    S("suspended"),
    I("inactive");

    private String status;

    BusinessCustomersStatus(String status)
    {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

Search DTO:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class BusinessCustomersSearchParams {

    private String title;

    private List<BusinessCustomersStatus> status;

    private LocalDateTime createdAt;

    private LocalDateTime updatedAt;
}
```

Search Specification:

```
public Page<BusinessCustomersFullDTO> findBusinessCustomers(BusinessCustomersSearchParams params, Pageable pageable)
    {
        Specification<BusinessCustomers> spec = (root, query, cb) -> {
            List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
            if (params.getTitle() != null) {
                predicates.add(cb.like(cb.lower(root.get("title")), "%" + params.getTitle().toLowerCase() + "%"));
            }

            Optional<BusinessCustomersStatus> optStatus = EnumSet.allOf(BusinessCustomersStatus.class)
                    .stream()
                    .filter(e -> e.name().equals(params.getStatus()))
                    .findAny();

            if(optStatus.isPresent()){
                final List<BusinessCustomersStatus> statuses = params.getStatus();
                if (statuses != null && !statuses.isEmpty()){
                    predicates.add(root.get("status").in(statuses));
                }
            }
            return cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
        };
        return businessCustomersService.findAll(spec, pageable).map(businessCustomersMapper::toFullDTO);
    }
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "business_customers")
public class BusinessCustomers implements Serializable {
   
    ..........
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "status", length = 20)
    private BusinessCustomersStatus status;
    ......
}
```

But I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.service.businesscustomers.BusinessCustomersStatus.4d29e059cf] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.service.businesscustomers.BusinessCustomersStatus.4d29e059cf
        at java.base/java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:273)
```

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

POC example: https://github.com/rcbandit111/Search_specification_POC

Comment: My it be duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12639791/what-is-the-reason-for-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-no-enum-const-class-e ?

Comment: I find `filter(e -> e.name().equals(params.getStatus()))` very suspicious. You are trying to compare a `String` with a `List<BusinessCustomersStatus>`. Additionally, could it be that you have old data / values in your database?

Comment: Yes, in this case this is not correct. How I can fix this? And no, the database data should not be a problem.

Comment: Here you can see the code example: https://github.com/rcbandit111/Search_specification_POC

Comment: I guess you should user a `JPA Converter` An example is https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-attribute-converters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are mixing several of the options exposed in my answer to your [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69163458/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-no-enum-constant-found).

Assuming that you are defining `status` as a `List` as in the example you provided:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
public class BusinessCustomersSearchParams {

    private String title;

    private List<BusinessCustomersStatus> status;

    private LocalDateTime createdAt;

    private LocalDateTime updatedAt;
}
```

You can try using in your `Specification` either an `in` clause:

```java
public Page<BusinessCustomersFullDTO> findBusinessCustomers(BusinessCustomersSearchParams params, Pageable pageable) {
    Specification<BusinessCustomers> spec = (root, query, cb) -> {
        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
        if (params.getTitle() != null) {
            predicates.add(cb.like(cb.lower(root.get("title")), "%" + params.getTitle().toLowerCase() + "%"));
        }
  
        // According to your comments, please, see this example
        // about how to wrap the List returned from your form
        final List<BusinessCustomersStatus> statuses = Optional.ofNullable(params.getStatus()).orElse(Collections.emptyList());
        if (statuses != null && !statuses.isEmpty()){
            predicates.add(root.get("status").in(statuses));
        }
        
        return cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
    };
    return businessCustomersService.findAll(spec, pageable).map(businessCustomersMapper::toFullDTO);
}
```

Or you can iterate over the `status` collection in order to verify each value and build an `or` predicate with the required filter criteria:

```java
public Page<BusinessCustomersFullDTO> findBusinessCustomers(BusinessCustomersSearchParams params, Pageable pageable) {
    Specification<BusinessCustomers> spec = (root, query, cb) -> {
        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
        if (params.getTitle() != null) {
            predicates.add(cb.like(cb.lower(root.get("title")), "%" + params.getTitle().toLowerCase() + "%"));
        }

        final List<BusinessCustomersStatus> statuses = params.getStatus();
        if (statuses != null && !statuses.isEmpty()){
            List<Predicate> statusPredicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

            EnumSet<BusinessCustomersStatus> businessCustomersStatusEnumSet = EnumSet.allOf(BusinessCustomersStatus.class);

            statuses.forEach(status -> {
                Optional<BusinessCustomersStatus> optStatus = businessCustomersStatusEnumSet
                    .stream()
                    .filter(e -> e.equals(status))
                    .findAny();

                if(optStatus.isPresent()){
                    statusPredicates.add(cb.equal(root.get("status"), cb.literal(status)));
                }    
            });
            
            predicates.add(
                cb.or(statusPredicates.toArray(new Predicate[statusPredicates.size()]))
            );
        }

        
        return cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
    };
    return businessCustomersService.findAll(spec, pageable).map(businessCustomersMapper::toFullDTO);
}
```

In fact, as you are already using the enumeration and not `String`s I think the `forEach` loop presented in the previous code can be simplified as follows:

```java
public Page<BusinessCustomersFullDTO> findBusinessCustomers(BusinessCustomersSearchParams params, Pageable pageable) {
    Specification<BusinessCustomers> spec = (root, query, cb) -> {
        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
        if (params.getTitle() != null) {
            predicates.add(cb.like(cb.lower(root.get("title")), "%" + params.getTitle().toLowerCase() + "%"));
        }

        final List<BusinessCustomersStatus> statuses = params.getStatus();
        if (statuses != null && !statuses.isEmpty()){
            List<Predicate> statusPredicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

            EnumSet<BusinessCustomersStatus> businessCustomersStatusEnumSet = EnumSet.allOf(BusinessCustomersStatus.class);

            statuses.forEach(status -> {
              if(businessCustomersStatusEnumSet.contains(status)){
                statusPredicates.add(cb.equal(root.get("status"), cb.literal(status)));
              }    
            });
            
            predicates.add(
                cb.or(statusPredicates.toArray(new Predicate[statusPredicates.size()]))
            );
        }

        
        return cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
    };
    return businessCustomersService.findAll(spec, pageable).map(businessCustomersMapper::toFullDTO);
}
```

Or even, with a different approach:

```java
public Page<BusinessCustomersFullDTO> findBusinessCustomers(BusinessCustomersSearchParams params, Pageable pageable) {
    Specification<BusinessCustomers> spec = (root, query, cb) -> {
        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
        if (params.getTitle() != null) {
            predicates.add(cb.like(cb.lower(root.get("title")), "%" + params.getTitle().toLowerCase() + "%"));
        }

        final List<BusinessCustomersStatus> statuses = params.getStatus();
        if (statuses != null && !statuses.isEmpty()){
            EnumSet<BusinessCustomersStatus> businessCustomersStatusEnumSet = EnumSet.allOf(BusinessCustomersStatus.class);

            List<Predicate> statusPredicates = businessCustomersStatusEnumSet.stream()
              .filter(status -> statuses.contains(status))
              .map(status -> cb.equal(root.get("status"), cb.literal(status)))
              .collect(Collectors.toList())
            ;
            
            if (statusPredicates != null && !statusPredicates.isEmpty()) {
              predicates.add(
                cb.or(statusPredicates.toArray(new Predicate[statusPredicates.size()]))
              );
            }
        }

        
        return cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
    };
    return businessCustomersService.findAll(spec, pageable).map(businessCustomersMapper::toFullDTO);
}
```

The first of the provided approaches is the one that should be used in a typical use case, although the last can probably solve the problem by removing the incorrect values, but the actual question remains: why you are receiving the incorrect enum value in first place? Please, review your database records seeking for incorrect ones, and be sure - sorry for saying, but sometimes it happens, I faced myself - that you use everywhere the annotation value, `A`, for instance, and not the value associated with it, `active`, continuing with the example; they are the values that should be stored in the database, those to be submitted by your frontend, etc.

---

If you need or prefer to use the `status` literal associated with your enumeration, you can follow the following approach.

First, modify your enum and provide a helper method in the conversion process:

```java
public enum BusinessCustomersStatus {
    ACTIVE("active"),
    ONBOARDING("onboarding"),
    NOT_VERIFIED("not_verified"),
    VERIFIED("verified"),
    SUSPENDED("suspended"),
    INACTIVE("inactive");

    private String status;

    BusinessCustomersStatus(String status)
    {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public static BusinessCustomersStatus fromStatus(String status) {
        switch (status) {
            case "active": {
                return ACTIVE;
            }

            case "onboarding": {
                return ONBOARDING;
            }

            case "not_verified": {
                return NOT_VERIFIED;
            }

            case "verified": {
                return VERIFIED;
            }

            case "suspended": {
                return SUSPENDED;
            }

            case "inactive": {
                return INACTIVE;
            }

            default: {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
                    String.format("Unkhown status: '%s'", status)
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, modify `BusinessCustomersSearchParams`  to use `String` instead of the enumeration for the `status` field:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
public class BusinessCustomersSearchParams {

    private String title;

    private List<String> status;

    private LocalDateTime createdAt;

    private LocalDateTime updatedAt;
}
```

Finally, modify your Specification to handle the conversion process. For instance:

```java
@Override
public Page<BusinessCustomersFullDTO> findBusinessCustomers(BusinessCustomersSearchParams params, Pageable pageable)
{
    Specification<BusinessCustomers> spec = (root, query, cb) -> {
        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
        if (params.getTitle() != null) {
            predicates.add(cb.like(cb.lower(root.get("description")), "%" + params.getTitle().toLowerCase() + "%"));
        }

        final List<String> statuses = Optional.ofNullable(params.getStatus()).orElse(Collections.emptyList());
        if (statuses != null && !statuses.isEmpty()){
            List<BusinessCustomersStatus> statusesAsEnum = statuses.stream()
                .map(status -> BusinessCustomersStatus.fromStatus(status))
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
                ;

            predicates.add(root.get("status").in(statusesAsEnum));
        }

        return cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
    };
    return businessCustomersService.findAll(spec, pageable).map(businessCustomersMapper::toFullDTO);
}
```

You can use the `fromStatus` method in the insertion process as well.

Having said that, I don't know if it what you need, but I think here you can use an [`AttributeConverter`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic-enums-attribute-converter). Consider for instance:

```java
import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import javax.persistence.Converter;

@Converter
public class BusinessCustomersStatusAttributeConverter
    implements AttributeConverter<BusinessCustomersStatus, String> {

  public String convertToDatabaseColumn( BusinessCustomersStatus value ) {
    if ( value == null ) {
      return null;
    }

    return value.getStatus();
  }

  public BusinessCustomersStatus convertToEntityAttribute( String value ) {
    if ( value == null ) {
      return null;
    }

    return BusinessCustomersStatus.fromStatus( value );
  }

}
```

You need to provide the additional `getStatus` method in your enumeration:

```java
package org.merchant.database.service.businesscustomers;

public enum BusinessCustomersStatus {
    ACTIVE("active"),
    ONBOARDING("onboarding"),
    NOT_VERIFIED("not_verified"),
    VERIFIED("verified"),
    SUSPENDED("suspended"),
    INACTIVE("inactive");

    private String status;

    BusinessCustomersStatus(String status)
    {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public static BusinessCustomersStatus fromStatus(String status) {
        switch (status) {
            case "active": {
                return ACTIVE;
            }

            case "onboarding": {
                return ONBOARDING;
            }

            case "not_verified": {
                return NOT_VERIFIED;
            }

            case "verified": {
                return VERIFIED;
            }

            case "suspended": {
                return SUSPENDED;
            }

            case "inactive": {
                return INACTIVE;
            }

            default: {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
                    String.format("Unkhown status: '%s'", status)
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, your `BusinessCustomers` entity should be modified to something like:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "business_customers")
public class BusinessCustomers implements Serializable {
   
    ..........
    @Convert( converter = BusinessCustomersStatusAttributeConverter.class )
    private BusinessCustomersStatus status;
    ......
}
```

Please, be aware that if you implement the `AttributeConverter` approach in the database the values stored will be as well the literal `status` associated with the enumeration, not the enumeration `name` itself. Please, keep the `@Enumerated` approach in `BusinessCustomers` if you prefer to store the enumeration values. If you used the `AttributeConverter` approach for testing, please, remember to update the values of the `status` column to those corresponding to the enumeration.

Finally, regarding your last comment, you are receiving `"status": "ACTIVE"`: this is because your Mapstruct `Mapper` is providing the `name` of the enum as the value for the `status` field in `BusinessCustomersFullDTO`. To handle the appropriate conversion, please, try the following:

```java
import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import org.mapstruct.Mapping;
import org.mapstruct.Named;
import org.merchant.config.BaseMapperConfig;
import org.merchant.database.entity.BusinessCustomers;
import org.merchant.database.service.businesscustomers.BusinessCustomersStatus;
import org.merchant.dto.businesscustomers.BusinessCustomersFullDTO;

@Mapper(config = BaseMapperConfig.class)
public interface BusinessCustomersMapper {

    @Mapping(source = "status", target = "status", qualifiedByName = "businessCustomersToDTOStatus")
    BusinessCustomersFullDTO toFullDTO(BusinessCustomers businessCustomers);


    @Named("busineessCustomersToDTOStatus")
    public static String businessCustomersToDTOStatus(final BusinessCustomersStatus status) {
        if (status == null) {
            return null;
        }

        return status.getStatus();
    }
}
```

In the code we are using `@Named` and `qualifiedByName` to provide the custom conversion. Please, see the [relevant documentation](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#selection-based-on-qualifiers).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238203/discussion-on-answer-by-jccampanero-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-no-enum).

Comment: I tried to implement the code with little modification but I get this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69746275/multiple-as-value-properties-defined

Answer (score 1):

You should define that [`enum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) with constant values, then the values won't be `instanceof` something (maybe it doesn't like the enumeration for some other reason, but it still reads `no enum constant`).

```
public static final int STATUS_ACTIVE       = 0;
public static final int STATUS_ONBOARDING   = 1;
public static final int STATUS_NOT_VERIFIED = 2;
public static final int STATUS_VERIFIED     = 3;
public static final int STATUS_SUSPENDED    = 4;
public static final int STATUS_INACTIVE     = 5;

public enum BusinessCustomersStatus {
   STATUS_ACTIVE,
   STATUS_ONBOARDING,
   STATUS_NOT_VERIFIED,
   STATUS_VERIFIED,
   STATUS_SUSPENDED,
   STATUS_INACTIVE
}
```

And `@Enumerated` should then be `EnumType.ORDINAL`:

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
@Column(name = "status")
```