# Multiple 'as-value' properties defined

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-rest

I want to create a ENUM which holds different statuses for possible database values and use them also to generate possible drop down statuses in FE:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonValue;

public enum BusinessCustomersStatus {
    A("active", "Active"),
    O("onboarding", "Onboarding"),
    NV("not_verified", "Not Verified"),
    V("verified", "Verified"),
    S("suspended", "Suspended"),
    I("inactive", "Inactive");

    private String shortName;

    private String fullName;

    BusinessCustomersStatus(String shortName, String fullName) {
        this.shortName = shortName;
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    // Define the status field as the enum representation by using @JsonValue
    @JsonValue
    public String getShortName() {
        return shortName;
    }

    @JsonValue
    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    // Use the fromStatus method as @JsonCreator
    @JsonCreator
    public static BusinessCustomersStatus fromStatus(String statusText) {
        for (BusinessCustomersStatus status : values()) {
            if (status.getShortName().equalsIgnoreCase(statusText)) {
                return status;
            }
        }

        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(String.format("Unknown status: '%s'", statusText));
    }
}
```

Full code:

https://github.com/rcbandit111/Search_specification_POC/blob/main/src/main/java/org/merchant/database/service/businesscustomers/BusinessCustomersStatus.java

But when I make a POST request to add a new record I get this error:

```
21:36:52.033 [http-nio-8000-exec-1] DEBUG HttpEntityMethodProcessor[traceDebug:91] - Writing [org.merchant.dto.tickets.TicketsFullDTO@1c7e1a52]
21:36:52.034 [http-nio-8000-exec-1] WARN  DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver[logException:207] - Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Problem with definition of [AnnotedClass org.merchant.database.service.tickets.TicketStatus]: Multiple 'as-value' properties defined ([method org.merchant.database.service.tickets.TicketStatus#getFullName()] vs [method org.merchant.database.service.tickets.TicketStatus#getShortName()]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Problem with definition of [AnnotedClass org.merchant.database.service.tickets.BusinessCustomersStatus]: Multiple 'as-value' properties defined ([method org.merchant.database.service.tickets.BusinessCustomersStatus#getFullName()] vs [method org.merchant.database.service.tickets.BusinessCustomersStatus#getShortName()]) (through reference chain: org.merchant.dto.tickets.TicketsFullDTO["status"])]
21:36:52.034 [http-nio-8000-exec-1] DEBUG OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor[afterCompletion:111] - Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
21:36:52.034 [http-nio-8000-exec-1] DEBUG DispatcherServlet[logResult:1131] - Completed 500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
21:36:52.035 [http-nio-8000-exec-1] DEBUG DispatcherServlet[traceDebug:91] - "ERROR" dispatch for POST "/api/error", parameters={}
21:36:52.035 [http-nio-8000-exec-1] DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping[getHandler:522] - Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
21:36:52.035 [http-nio-8000-exec-1] DEBUG OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor[preHandle:86] - Opening JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
21:36:52.036 [http-nio-8000-exec-1] DEBUG HttpEntityMethodProcessor[writeWithMessageConverters:268] - Using 'application/json', given [application/json, text/plain, */*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json, application/json, application/*+json]
21:36:52.036 [http-nio-8000-exec-1] DEBUG HttpEntityMethodProcessor[traceDebug:91] - Writing [{timestamp=Wed Oct 27 21:36:52 UTC 2021, status=500, error=Internal Server Error, path=/api/manageme (truncated)...]
21:36:52.036 [http-nio-8000-exec-1] DEBUG OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor[afterCompletion:111] - Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
21:36:52.037 [http-nio-8000-exec-1] DEBUG DispatcherServlet[logResult:1127] - Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 500
 Multiple 'as-value' properties defined ^C22:18:41.117 [SpringApplicationShutdownHook] DEBUG ApplicationAvailabilityBean[onApplicationEvent:77] - Application availability state ReadinessState changed from ACCEPTING_TRAFFIC to REFUSING_TRAFFIC
```

Note that I have changed TicketStatus with BusinessCustomersStatus into the error stack.

When I make a request I send this payload:

```
{"title":"ascascasc","description":"ascascasc","status":"assigned","submitDate":"2021-10-13T00:00:00.000Z","category":"service","severity":"normal"}
```

Do you know how I can solve this issue?

Comment: @jccampanero can you advise please?

Comment: To clarify, you would like this code, for instance: `ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();  mapper.writeValue(System.out, BusinessCustomersStatus.A);` to produce `{"shortName": "active", "fullName": "Active"}`?

Comment: Where  I need to put this code?

Comment: That's not code you need to add, I'm just trying to understand how you want your `enum` to look when it is converted to JSON.

Comment: When I get the ENUM data I use this code tp convert it to DTO: `Arrays.stream(TicketStatus.values()).map(g -> new TicketStatusTypesDTO(g.getShortName(), g.getFullName())).collect(Collectors.toList());` This produces: `[{"code":"new","name":"New"},{"code":"assigned","name":"Assigned"},{"code":"in_progress","name":"In-progress"},{"code":"closed","name":"Closed"}]` So far it's working fine. Please see the post to see with what payload I get the error when I make POST request.

Comment: So why do you have two `@JsonValue` annotations on your `enum`? If you just have the annotation on `getShortName` it should work.

Comment: The proposal to remove the annotation works but I would like to return the full name. Right now I get for example into JSON `status: "A"`. Is there any solution?

Comment: If you leave the annotation on `getFullName`, but remove it from `getShortName` I'd expect you to get "Active". Is that not what happens? But now I'm confused because your @JsonCreator uses the shortName, not the fullName.

Comment: I am sorry @PeterPenzov, I just see your comment. I am very happy to hear that you were able to solve the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it may work if changed like this

```
public String getShortName() {
    return shortName;
}

@JsonValue
public String getFullName() {
    return fullName;
}
```