# Spring boot Enum Multiple 'as-value' properties defined error

Tags: java, spring-boot, enums

I am writing an enum class to import values via JSON for an API service:

```
public enum MonthEnum {

    JANUARY(1, "January"),
    FEBRUARY(2, "February"),
    MARCH(3, "March"),
    APRIL(4, "April"),
    MAY(5, "May"),
    JUNE(6, "June"),
    JULY(7, "July"),
    AUGUST(8, "August"),
    SEPTEMBER(9, "September"),
    OCTOBER(10, "October"),
    NOVEMBER(11, "November"),
    DECEMBER(12, "December");


    public final int code;
    public final String lowerName;


    private MonthEnum(
            int code,
            String lowerName
    ) {
        this.code = code;
        this.lowerName = lowerName;
    }

    @JsonValue
    public int getCode() {

        return code;
    }

    @JsonValue
    public String getLowerName() {

        return lowerName;
    }

    private static String getErrorMessage(String value){
        List<Integer> codes = Arrays.stream(values())
                .map(e -> valueOf(e.name()).code)
                .toList();
        List<String> fullNames = Arrays.stream(values())
                .map(e -> valueOf(e.name()).lowerName)
                .toList();
        List<String> processedList = StreamUtils.zip(
                        codes.stream(),
                        fullNames.stream(),
                        (code, name) -> String.format("%s (%s)", code, name))
                .toList();
        return "Unknown value: " +
                value +
                ". Allowed values are: [" +
                String.join(", ", processedList) +
                "]";
    }

    private static String getErrorMessage(int value){
        List<Integer> codes = Arrays.stream(values())
                .map(e -> valueOf(e.name()).code)
                .toList();
        List<String> fullNames = Arrays.stream(values())
                .map(e -> valueOf(e.name()).lowerName)
                .toList();
        List<String> processedList = StreamUtils.zip(
                        codes.stream(),
                        fullNames.stream(),
                        (code, name) -> String.format("%s (%s)", code, name))
                .toList();
        return "Unknown value: " +
                value +
                ". Allowed values are: [" +
                String.join(", ", processedList) +
                "]";
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public static MonthEnum of(String value) {
        Optional<MonthEnum> month = Arrays.stream(MonthEnum.values())
                .filter(e -> e.lowerName.equalsIgnoreCase(value))
                .findFirst();
        return month.orElseThrow(
                () -> new EnumArgumentNotValidException(getErrorMessage(value))
        );
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public static MonthEnum of(int value) {
        Optional<MonthEnum> month = Arrays.stream(MonthEnum.values())
                .filter(e -> e.code == value)
                .findFirst();
        return month.orElseThrow(
                () -> new EnumArgumentNotValidException(getErrorMessage(value))
        );
    }
}
```

what I want is for the user to be able to use as input either the months expressed according to whole numbers from 1 to 12, or directly using the names by ingnoring the case (uppercase, lowercase or mixed):

```
{
"period": [1, 2, 3]
}
```

or

```
{
"period": ["january", "february", "March"]
}
```

or

```
{
"period": ["january", "February", 3]
}
```

Also, I am handling the error with a message if a used parameter (e.g., 13) is inserted in the request.

unfortunately I get this message error

```
 Problem with definition of [AnnotedClass org.cnr.urbantreedb.enums.MonthEnum]: Multiple 'as-value' properties defined ([method org.cnr.urbantreedb.enums.MonthEnum#getCode()] vs [method org.cnr.urbantreedb.enums.MonthEnum#getLowerName()])

Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content-Type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' is not supported]
```

This is solved by removing from either method the @JsonValue annotation, as written on this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69746275/multiple-as-value-properties-defined). But in doing so I lose the features I want to develop.

Comment: You can achieve this by implementing a custom deserializer.

Comment: Thanks for your time. A Custom Deserializer only for MonthEnum?

Comment: Yes. It is not much coding. Check here https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-enums

Comment: Thanks, you are very kind. This is my first time to implement a Custom Deserializer, I hope I can do it.

Comment: Mar-Z the baeldung link is full of errors. For example in public class CustomEnumDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<MyEnumClass> is missing a public CustomEnumDeserializer() {
        super(MyEnumClass.class);
    }