# static initializer interfering with emma

Tags: java, junit, code-coverage, emma, static-initializer

I've written a class that has every line covered through JUnit/emma (its a fairly basic class).

Emma's eclipse output shows all lines in green (covered). However, emma's report (HTML) shows that I've missed 1 instruction. It highlights the class in yellow (public class X).

The missed instruction appears to be related to a "static initializer". I'm familiar with them, and this particular class has no

```
static {

}
```

block in it. It has no static methods at all. It does have 4 public static final ints. It also contains an enum.

The HTML output indicates:

```
class X$1
<static initializer>
```

as being the instruction (and method) that is not covered.

Where is this mystery instruction coming from? How can I test it?

I dont have any inner classes in this file, I can't even explain where the $1 is coming from.

Comment: As an experiment, you could refactor the enum into its own class to see if the message goes away.

Comment: This is from enum. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834632/java-enum-and-additional-class-files