# switch causes NoClassDefFoundError in tomcat using undefined inner classes

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a very simple enumeration

**my.package.data.util**

```
public enum Mode
{
    SQLEXPORT, PREVIEW, PRINT
}
```

Which is used in another class as enums should be used

**my.package.program.ComponentController**

```
switch (_mode) { // line 278, _mode is of type my.package.data.util.Mode
case PREVIEW:
    // Do thing for preview
    break;
case SQLEXPORT:
    // Do thing for SQL
    break;
case PRINT:
    // Do thing for print
    break;
default:
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

These two classes are in the same project and are compiled into a `jar` file.

A web project is then using this library (placed into the `WEB-INF/lib` folder). But, when the time comes to use this library, and most specifically that switch, a `NoClassDefFoundError` occurs:

> NoClassDefFoundError: my/package/program/ComponentController$1
>
> at my.package.program.ComponentController.doCall(ComponentController.java:278)

This is something I cannot understand on several levels:

1. Why Java tries to load an *inner class* (as visible by the `$1`). There is no inner class present in `ComponentController`, and never has been.
2. Why Java thinkgs the switch is using this internal class as its argument
3. Where the `my.package.data.util.Mode` class vanished

What is happening here?

---

*Further information not in the original question*

- `ComponentController` extends another class, `SessionBuilder`. This class also has no inner classes

I decompiled the `ComponentController` using `javap` and tried to find interesting things in the resulting byte code.

It appears that there is indeed an inner class in the byte code:

```
public class my.package.program.ComponentController extends my.other.package.SessionBuilder
  SourceFile: "ComponentController.java"
  InnerClasses:
       static #192 of #2; //class my/package/program/ComponentController$1 of class my/package/program/ComponentController
```

This class is used whenever `my.package.data.util.Mode` is referenced:

```
#192 = Class              #486          //  my/package/program/ComponentController$1
#193 = Utf8               
#194 = Utf8               InnerClasses
#195 = Utf8               _mode
#196 = Utf8               Lmy/package/data/util/Mode;
```

And also, when the switch actually occurs:

```
183: getstatic     #102                // Field my/package/program/ComponentController$1.$SwitchMap$my$package$data$util$Mode:[I
186: aload_0       
187: getfield      #5                  // Field _mode:Lmy/package/data/util/Mode;
190: invokevirtual #103                // Method my/package/data/util/Mode.ordinal:()I
193: iaload        
194: tableswitch   { // 1 to 3
   1: 220
   2: 335
   3: 440
   default: 516
}
```

---

Further investigation into the questions linked by *Rich* produced something interesting: The built `jar` from the library project differ in the local tomcat installation and the one used to produce the `jar` for the production server:

Left: jar in `WEB-INF/lib` via local tomcat by eclipse, Right: `jar` as built by ANT

[image: JAR Diff]

It now seems like the build process used by eclipse when publishing to a local tomcat differs from what ANT does (which is AFAIK just a simple `javac` call)

---

Alright, now I just copied the `jar` created by ANT into the local tomcats `WEB-INF/lib` and everything works fine. Of course, this means that after every change in the library project, I have to manually copy the new `jar` to my tomcat lib.

I filed this as a bug report at eclipse and will report back with any news.

Comment: How did you link the fact that this error is due to this switch ? I think the point of interest in code missing in your question is the line 278 of your ComponentController file.

Comment: Because line 278 is `switch (_mode)`, I will add that information to the code in the question

Comment: Have you tried decompiling the .jar to see what javac has done? It sounds like javac has interned the enum - is it the only place it is used?

Comment: @Rich I have looked at it using *JD-GUI*, but it unsurprisingly shows nothing interesting. I am currently trying to wade through the Bytecode output from `javap` and see if it helps. I will add anything I find to the question

Comment: Is it possible that your class file for ComponentController is old version. Did you try rebuild?

Comment: @talex I rebuilt and deployed the tomcat several times, but I will try to remove everything manually again to make sure. The thing is though, this code has not changed in ages, it just now appeared after I tried to run this on my local machine - On the production server this same code runs perfectly fine.

Comment: No difference in JVM versions between your machine and production, I suppose?

Comment: @Rich No, unfortunately nothing this easy. I just added even more information I found when inspecting the JARs from production and development

Comment: @F.P , I am facing the same issue after so many years. Any idea about the fix ? I am using java 1.8

Comment: @ysn I'm convinced it was an eclipse specific bug. We've since switched to IntelliJ, so I'm sorry to say that I cannot really recall any solution to this issue

Answer (score 8):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834632/java-enum-and-additional-class-files) question:

> ...Sun's Javac 1.6 creates an additional synthetic class each time you use a switch on an Enum.

And according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24473247/java-enum-noclassdeffounderror) question you aren't alone.

Comment: Okay, I see how this might be done. Then the question is: Why doesn't it work in my case?

Answer (score 2):

From my experience, the problem is that this new class is not deployed by Eclipse, but it is generated in the build process.