# why is <filename>$1.class generated?

Tags: java, class, enums, switch-statement

```
enum Day{ SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY}  

class Enum1 {  

  public static void main(String args[]) {  

    Day day=Day.MONDAY;  

    switch(day) {  
      case SUNDAY:   
        System.out.println("sunday");  
        break;  
      case MONDAY:   
        System.out.println("monday");  
        break;  
      default:  
        System.out.println("other day");
    }
  }
}
```

I see that `Enum1.class` ,`Day.class`, and `Enum1$1.class` when I compile this code. When I comment out the switchcase part only `Enum1.class` and `Day.class` are generated.

What in the switchcase is the cause of generating an extra `Enum1$1.class` file?

Comment: `javap -verbose Enum1$1.class` can show you the contents of that class file, which might be a clue.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834632/java-enum-and-additional-class-files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `javap` on classes in the package `de.lhorn`:

**`Day.class`**

```
public final class de.lhorn.so.Day extends java.lang.Enum<de.lhorn.so.Day> {
  public static final de.lhorn.so.Day SUNDAY;
  public static final de.lhorn.so.Day MONDAY;
  public static final de.lhorn.so.Day TUESDAY;
  public static final de.lhorn.so.Day WEDNESDAY;
  public static final de.lhorn.so.Day THURSDAY;
  public static final de.lhorn.so.Day FRIDAY;
  public static final de.lhorn.so.Day SATURDAY;
  public static de.lhorn.so.Day[] values();
  public static de.lhorn.so.Day valueOf(java.lang.String);
  static {};
}
```

**`Enum1.class`**

```
public class de.lhorn.so.Enum1 {
  public de.lhorn.so.Enum1();
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}
```

**`Enum$1.class`**

```
class de.lhorn.so.Enum1$1 {
  static final int[] $SwitchMap$de$lhorn$so$Day;
  static {};
}
```

So the `switch` causes `javac` to generate the additional `static final int[] $SwitchMap$de$lhorn$so$Day;`.