# How does using Enumerations increases the executable size?

Tags: android, c++, enums, apk, executable

One of google's tips to reduce `APK` size is by avoiding using `Enumerations` , they said : `A single enum can add about 1.0 to 1.4 KB of size to your app's classes.dex file.` , How that is possible ? and is it the same case for natice ( C/C++ ) code ?
Source : https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/reduce-apk-size.html

Comment: check this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hzs6OBcvNQE&feature=youtu.be if it helps. also search similar topics @ https://plus.google.com/communities/116342551728637785407

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dex bloating for java enums [has been discussed in SO  before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834632/java-enum-and-additional-class-files). Enumerations in C/C++ do not bloat code at all. They are just numeric constants and code size for every switch takes several bytes per case statement. If enum values are consecutive and not large, switch can be translated to a TBB instruction which requires only a byte for every case plus size of the command itself.