# Origin of additional generated $1 .class file

Tags: java, java-6

I found that when using `switch case` statement with an `Enumeration` as parameter. a new `.class` file called ClassName$1.class will be generated.

Can you explain to me the origin of this .class file ?

```
public class MayJavaApp{

    private static NewEnum ok;

    public String doSomthing() {
        NewEnum value=null;
        switch (value) {
            default: return "other";
        }
    }

}
```

The target directory contains:

- MayJavaApp.class
- MayJavaApp$1.class

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1834632/8116173 I think that link might be helpful, you can read about similar (if not the same) topic.

Comment: Interesting. It's the switch that does it. The static field is irrelevant.

Comment: @Dan
My question is different from the other because I'm looking for the origin of this class

Comment: The solution : because a Java enum implements implecitly Comparable