# What actually happens when an enum is used in a switch statement?

Tags: java, enums, switch-statement

According [Oracle's documentation on Switch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html), a switch-case structure can work with some numerical primitives like byte, short, char and int (and their wrapper classes), as well as String and *enums*.

It's also true that enum classes automatically get a `.ordinal()` method that returns the constant's position in its enum declaration.

Is it the case that, when enums are used in a switch-case structure, specifically in the `case VENUS:` kind of label, that **behind the scenes, the `.ordinal()` method is being automatically called during compilation?** Much like how `.toString()` gets called in println()?

It's not explicitly stated in the documentation I've looked at what exactly happens or how it's possible that a switch statement, which (ignoring String) typically works with numerical primitives (via autoboxing if necessary), can work with an enum constant.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834632/java-enum-and-additional-class-files, but `javap -c` is still your friend.