# android - how to keep enum from proguard

Tags: android, enums, proguard

In my proguard, I have the following to keep public enums from being obfuscated.

```
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}
```

My question is, does this also keep the public enum **Currency** in a class like this?

```
public class Foo {
    public enum **Currency** {PENNY, NICKLE, DIME, QUARTER};

    ...
}
```

If not, what do I have to add separately?

Adding the following doesn't seem to help.

```
-keepattributes InnerClasses
```

Any advice? Thanks

Comment: For Kotlin: Add the following line inside the 'proguard-rules.pro' file. 
-keepnames class your.package.EnumName

Answer (score 25):

You could try

```
-keep public enum com.stuff.TheEnclosingClass$** {
    **[] $VALUES;
    public *;
}
```

As shown on this answer [Proguard won't keep a class member's enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6285623/proguard-wont-keep-a-class-members-enums)

Just don't forget to put

```
-keepattributes InnerClasses
```

Answer (score 6):

Can you try to tell proguard to keep the specific class:

```
-keep class com.xxx.Foo { *; }
```

Answer (score 4):

The option `-keepclassmembers` only keeps the class members; in this case the methods `values()` and `valueOf(String)` of all enum classes. The wild card `*` also matches internal classes.

If you for some reason want to preserve the inner class with its original name, you can specify:

```
-keep class somepackage.Foo$Currency
```

That should only be necessary if your application accesses the class through reflection.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to safe **enum names and all fields, methods** for it:

```
-keep enum * { *; }
```