# How to keep Enum type fields in proguard?

Tags: android, enums, gson, proguard, android-proguard

Here is my Entity class:

```
class Entity{
    private String id;
    Object content;
    private Type type;
    public enum Type{type1, type2, type3}
}
```

Depending on `type` field I pass respective the class to

```
gson.fromJson(json, <type1/2/3 class, depending on field type>);
```

But I am using proguard, and this obfuscate the type value, so I am not able to determine which class to use.

I tried to keep type field but its not keeping. Here is my code:

```
-keepclassmembers enum * { *; }
-keepclassmembers class com.mypkg.Entity {
    private java.lang.String id;
    private com.mypkg.Entity.Type type;
 }
```

I see that id is being kept, but not the type field.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6285623/) may help.

```
-keep public enum com.mypkg.Entity$** {
    **[] $VALUES;
    public *;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue using Kotlin. Try to use `@Keep` annotation

Example:

```
enum class Color {
    @Keep RED,
    @Keep GREEN,
    @Keep BLUE
}
```