# Create an array in which every position is an enum type

Tags: java, arrays, enums

Hi I would like to create an array in which every position is represented by the value of an enum.

For instance:

```
public enum type{

  green,blue,black,gray;

}
```

Now i want to create an array in which every position is green,blue,...

I'll be clearer. I would like to create an array in which the position is rapresented by a value of enum class.instead int[] array = new int[10] create int[] array = new int[type.value]

Comment: You want to number your array by color?

Comment: I don't think that's possible; arrays need to know their size, and an enum - although internally handled somewhat like a number - aren't numbers so no size can be derived from them.

Comment: @G.Bach  Ok excellent I would know this

Comment: Can you present your use case (what do you want with this array)?

Answer (score 6):

It's `type[] allValues = type.values()`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163076/how-is-values-implemented-for-java-6-enums).

Alternatively you can use [`EnumSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html):

```
EnumSet<type> types = EnumSet.allOf(type.class);
```

which gives you high-performance `Set` implementation filled with your enum's values.

PS: You should name enum class beginning with big letter (CamelCase).

**EDIT:**

Seems you want array of [ordinal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal%28%29) positions of your emum's values (why would anybody use an Array instead of right Collection nowadays?):

```
type[] colors = type.values();
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(colors.length);
for (type color : colors) {
  list.add(color.ordinal());
}
Integer[] array = list.toArray(new Integer[0]);
```

**EDIT2:** Maybe you want `Map<Integer, type>` with keys and values like `0 => green, 1 => blue, 2 => black, 3=> gray` (the question still isn't clear)?

Answer (score 2):

Please first correct me if I'm wrong: you're trying to associate each color with an `int` value.

If so, what you're looking for is an [associative array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array), which in Java is modelled as a [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). So you can use some `Map<type, Integer>` to achieve what you want (preferably an `EnumMap` which is optimized for using `Enum` keys).

```
// I renamed your "type" to Color
Map<Color, Integer> map = new EnumMap<Color, Integer>(Color.class);
map.put(Color.BLUE, 3);
```

However, if you really want to use an array, you can make use of the `ordinal()` method of your enum constants (which returns an `int` representing the constant's position in the enum declaration, starting from 0):

```
int[] ints = new int[Color.values().length];
ints[Color.BLUE.ordinal()] = 3;
```

---

If this association is meant to be unique for your entire application (if you never need to associate a color with more than one value at the same time; in other words, if it's never the case that some client stores `BLUE --> 2` and some other stores `BLUE --> 3`), then it would be better to store that value in the enum itself:

```
enum Color {
    GREEN, BLUE, BLACK, GRAY;

    private int value;

    // ...getter and setter for value...

}
```

Then you can write:

```
Color.BLUE.setValue(8);
```

And for reading the values:

```
for (Color c : Color.values()) {
    System.out.println("There are " + c.getValue() + " occurences of " + c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
 MyColor[] myList;
```

then

```
 myList = new MyColor[20];
```

nb, I would not use `type` as the name of the enum as it does not have a good meaning.  Something like color is better.

Answer (score 0):

You want an array of `type` objects? You can call `type[] types = type.values()`

Answer (score 0):

Enumerations are extensions of java.lang.Enum, so you can use the methods of java.lang.Enum to use an enumeration as a dimension of an array.

*enumeration*.**values().length** renders the size of the enumeration;

*enumValue*.**ordinal()** renders the index of a value in the enumeration.

For instance:

```
public class thisClass {
    enum thisEnum = {valA, valB, valC, valD, valE }
    private int[] arrayForThisEnum;

    public thisClass() {
        this.arrayForThisEnum = new int[thisEnum.values().length];
        // further initialization
    }

    public void addOne(thisEnum xxx) {
        this.arrayForThisEnum[xxx.ordinal()]++;
    }
}
```