# How to retrieve Enum name using the id?

Tags: java, enums

I have the `enum` as:

```
public enum EnumStatus {

    PASSED(40L, "Has Passed"),
    AVERAGE(60L, "Has Average Marks"),
    GOOD(80L, "Has Good Marks");

    private java.lang.String name;

    private java.lang.Long id;

    EnumStatus(Long id, java.lang.String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public java.lang.String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public java.lang.Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

I have to get the Enum names(`PASSED`, `AVERAGE`, `GOOD`) using the ids only(40,60, 80). How do I do it?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Create a static method in your `enum` which searches in `values` (implicit method/member, don't know exactly which is it) and returns the corresponding value. For cases in which the method can not find a matching value, you should create a special entry, e.g. `UNKNOWN`, which you can return. This way, you do not have to return `null`, which is always a bad idea.

```
public static EnumStatus getById(Long id) {
    for(EnumStatus e : values()) {
        if(e.id.equals(id)) return e;
    }
    return UNKNOWN;
}
```

Btw - your code seems to be wrong. The bracket after `GOOD` seems to not belong there.

Comment: IMHO, you should not return null in this kind of Enum's methods. A RuntimeException (i.e. IllegalArgumentException) would be better.

Comment: I think you're right, `null` is quite ugly. I'm also a fan of dummy values so that the enum would contain an additional value `UNKNOWN` with values which don't match to anything. Of course this is dependent on your environment.

Answer (score 17):

This can be done using a static map along with a static initializer:

```
public enum EnumStatus {

    PASSED(40L, "Has Passed"),
    AVERAGE(60L, "Has Average Marks"),
    GOOD(80L, "Has Good Marks");

    private static final Map<Long, EnumStatus> byId = new HashMap<Long, EnumStatus>();
    static {
        for (EnumStatus e : EnumStatus.values()) {
            if (byId.put(e.getId(), e) != null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("duplicate id: " + e.getId());
            }
        }
    }

    public static EnumStatus getById(Long id) {
        return byId.get(id);
    }

    // original code follows

    private java.lang.String name;

    private java.lang.Long id;

    EnumStatus(Long id, java.lang.String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public java.lang.String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public java.lang.Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

}
```

This will give an `O(1)` `getById()` method, and will automatically detect if you accidentally have duplicate ids in the enum.

Comment: I like your idea with using the map for constant access times. For big enums surely a good thing. Also checking the return value of put is really cool.

Comment: Regarding O(1) for this kind of methods, if such id and the inner ordinal are related by an equation, you can leverage the generated static array to get O(1) (see my answer).

Comment: @NPE I really like the idea of a static map and checking for the invariant that each constant has a unique id.Thanks.+1.

Answer (score 3):

You make this work as follows:

```
public static String fromId(long id) {
        for (EnumStatus es : EnumStatus.values()) {
            if (es.id.equals(id)) {
                return es.getName();
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static EnumStatus getById(long id)
{
  for (EnumStatus e : EnumStatus.values())
  {
    if (id == e.getId()) return e;
  } 
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("oh no");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a method in your `Enum` and get it by passing ids.

```
 public static ArrayList<EnumStatus> getEnumStatusById(ArrayList<Long> idList) {
    ArrayList<EnumStatus> listById = new ArrayList();
    for(EnumStatus es: EnumStatus.values()) {
        if( idList.contains(es.getId())) {
            listById.add(es);
        }
    }
    return listById;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Define contract**

```
/**
 * Contract that will allow Types with id to have generic implementation.
 */
public interface IdentifierType<T> {
  T getId();
}
```

**Apply contract**

```
public enum EntityType implements IdentifierType<Integer> {
  ENTITY1(1, "ONE), ENTITY2(2, "TWO");

  private Integer id;
  private String name;

  private EntityType(int id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
  }

  public static EntityType valueOf(Integer id) {
    return EnumHelper.INSTANCE.valueOf(id, EntityType.values());
  }

  @Override
  public Integer getId() {
    return id;
  }
}
```

**Helper/Util**

```
public enum EnumHelper {
  INSTANCE;

  /**
   * This will return {@link Enum} constant out of provided {@link Enum} values with the specified id.
   * @param id the id of the constant to return.
   * @param values the {@link Enum} constants of specified type.
   * @return the {@link Enum} constant.
   */
  public <T extends IdentifierType<S>, S> T valueOf(S id, T[] values) {
    if (!values[0].getClass().isEnum()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Values provided to scan is not an Enum");
    }

    T type = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < values.length && type == null; i++) {
        if (values[i].getId().equals(id)) {
            type = values[i];
        }
    }

    return type;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nihal, you have got a lot of replies answering how to find the right enum element.
But I have the feeling you wanted also to have the name of the element like **"PASSED" instead of "Has Passed"**.

Please call for  **.name()** to get **"PASSED"**.
Extending the answer of Josua: `getById(40L).name();`

and EnumStatus.PASSED.getName() to get in your case **"Has Passed"**.

Answer (score 1):

This **pattern** can help you:

```
public interface Identifiable<T extends Number> {

    @Nonnull
    T getId();
}

public final class GettableById<K extends Number, V extends Enum<V> & Identifiable<K>> {

    @Nonnull
    private final Map<K, V> idToValue;


    public GettableById(@Nonnull V[] values) {
        this.idToValue = Arrays.stream(values)
                .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableMap(Identifiable::getId, v -> v));
    }

    @Nonnull
    public V getById(@Nonnull K id) {
        var value = idToValue.get(id);
        if (value != null) {
            return value;
        }
        throw new NullPointerException("Cannot get value by id: %s".formatted(id));
    }
}

public enum DataType implements Identifiable<Short> {

    ANNUAL((short) 1), QUARTERLY((short) 2);

    private static final GettableById<Short, DataType> companion = new GettableById<>(values());

    @Nonnull
    private final Short id;


    public static DataType getById(Short id) {
        return companion.getById(id);
    }

    DataType(@Nonnull Short id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Nonnull
    @Override
    public Short getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Java 8 introduced `Optional` you can use it as a return type. Consider implementing like:

```
public static Optional<EnumStatus> fromId(Long id) {
    for (EnumStatus e: values()) {
        if (e.id.equals(id)) {
            return Optional.of(e);
        }
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

Or using Stream API:

```
public static Optional<EnumStatus> fromId(Long id) {
    return Stream.of(values())
            .filter(e -> e.id.equals(id))
            .findFirst();
}
```

In the book *Effective Java 3rd Edition* the author *Joshua Bloch* recommends an effective solution which also uses `Optional` as a return type:

```
private static final Map<String, Operation> stringToEnum =
    Stream.of(values()).collect(
        toMap(Object::toString, e -> e));

public static Optional<Operation> fromString(String symbol) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(stringToEnum.get(symbol));
}
```

Bloch's reasoning for using `Optional`:

> ... note that the `fromString` method returns an `Optional<Operation>`. This
> allows the method to indicate that the string that was passed in does not represent
> a valid operation, and it forces the client to confront this possibility

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over all the values and compare Id

```
for (EnumStatus  enumStatus : EnumStatus.values()) {
   if (..) {..}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the enum's ordinal has a clear relationship with this kind of ids, enabling a neat way to get O(1) in these methods. In your code, it is clear that

`EnumStatus.X = 40 + 20 * ordinal`,

so you can leverage the [static array that is generated under the hoods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163076/how-is-values-implemented-for-java-6-enums).

```
public static EnumStatus fromId(Long id) {
    int index = (id - 40L) / 20L;
    return values()[index];
}
```

Comment: I think this ought to at least validate that the assumption is correct. Otherwise, this can easily lead to fragile code.