# Java nonconstant expressions in switch statements

Tags: java, enums

I have an enum class that looks like the following:

```
public enum MyEnum {
    VALUE1("value.1"),
    VALUE2("value.2");

    private String value;
    private MyEnum(String value) { this.value = value; }

    public String getId() { return id; }
}
```

I want to have a switch statement on the values of the enum. Something like the following:

```
switch (myString) {
case MyEnum.VALUE1.getId():
   ...
}
```

I get the following compile time error: case expressions must be constant expressions.

Is there any way to get this to work with an enum and switch statement? The reason why I added values to the enum is because I want some IDs with "." and other nonallowed characters.

Comment: So some Enums have the same ID?

Comment: Noe, you can either use the enum values directly (`VALUE1`) or use the Strings ("value.1" - requires Java 7) or not use a `switch` (`if (...getId.equals(...))`

Comment: Do you essentially want to find the enum instance given an id?

Comment: You need to get the enum for the string, and switch on that. You can not have non-constant cases.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add a static method that accepts the `String id` as a parameter and returns the corresponding `MyEnum`:

```
public enum MyEnum {
    VALUE1("value.1"),
    VALUE2("value.2");

    private String id;

    private MyEnum(String value) {
        this.id = value;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public static MyEnum fromId(String id){
        for(MyEnum e:MyEnum.values()){
            if(e.getId().equals(id)){
                return e;
            }
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("Enum not found");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String value = "value.2";
        switch(MyEnum.fromId(value)){
        case VALUE1:
            System.out.println("ID 1");
        break;
        case VALUE2:
            System.out.println("ID 2");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your enum has a main method?  Does that work?  I've never tried that.

Comment: Store the `values()` in it's own field. This will improve efficiency.

Comment: Yes, enums have almost all of the same features of classes, I included the main method as a test.

Comment: @Obicere Just wondering but, wouldn't you think the enum is doing that under the hood?

Comment: @KevinBowersox not at all. It has to reload the enums every call or else modifications can be made. It's a weird statement, but I am 100% certain on this one. I will go find the code that reloads it now.

Comment: @Obicere Thanks for the reply.  I am interested in seeing it, might be tomorrow though, almost bed time.

Comment: @KevinBowersox The method gets added by the JVM but delegates to: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/lang/Class.java#Class.getEnumConstants%28%29

Answer (score 0):

Go the other way: instead of looking up each enum's id in the case statements, look up the id's enum in the switch statement.

```
switch (MyEnum.getEnumById(myString)) {
case VALUE1:
  //  ./..
  break;
case VALUE2:
  //  ./..
  break;
case VALUE3:
  //  ./..
  break;
}
```

There are several ways to write the getEnumById method.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15380243/how-to-retrieve-enum-name-using-the-id]) has a few options.