# Get enum by id [JAVA]

Tags: java, enums

i dont know how to effective get name of my enum type in java
I have:

```
public enum EventType{
    event_one(1, "ONE"), event_two(2, "TWO");.........

    private final int value;
    private final String eventName;

    private EventType(int EventType, String name) {
        this.value = EventType;
        this.eventName = name;
    }

    public String getEventName() {
        return eventName;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

}
```

And now, i want get `eventName` by id.. `enum.get(1); //ONE`
What is best way? For loop? Or is there any other way?

Comment: You could automatically put them into a `Map<Integer,EventType>`, and use the map to look up the values.

Comment: The following post should help you: :)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15380243/how-to-retrieve-enum-name-using-the-id

Comment: Or, if your event IDs are sequential, you could use `EventType.values()[id - 1]`

Comment: If the ids are sequential, something along `public static String getName(int id) { return values()[id-1].getEventName();}` could do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need an "id". Use `enum.ordinal()` instead. Then you can just do something like this:

```
public String getEventName(int id) { return EventType.values[id].getName(); }
```

Comment: Thank you. i think, its best way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `EventType.values()[position-1].getEventName()` if your values are in [order](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal()). Second approach is to use Map and get the Enum by code and retrieve event Name. Below is an example of the  2 approaches mentioned.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

enum EventType {
    event_one(1, "ONE"), event_two(2, "TWO");

    private final int value;
    private final String eventName;

    private EventType(int EventType, String name) {
        this.value = EventType;
        this.eventName = name;
    }

    public String getEventName() {
        return eventName;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    static Map<Integer, EventType> map = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        for (EventType catalog : EventType.values()) {
            map.put(catalog.value, catalog);
        }
    }

    public static EventType getByCode(int code) {
        return map.get(code);
    }
    public static EventType getByPosition(int positionCode) {
        return EventType.values()[positionCode - 1];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name = EventType.getByCode(1).getEventName();
        System.out.println(EventType.getByPosition(1).getEventName());
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}
```

Output

```
ONE
ONE
```