# difference between Enum and enum

Tags: java, enums

enum has `valueOf(string)` method to get enum constant and the same type of method present in `java.lang.Enum` class having name `valueOf(enumClassName, string)`
I found both are giving same output. Then what are other differences. If no difference then why JSL added `Enum.valueOf()`?

```
enum Season {
    WINTER,SUMMER
}

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String season = "WINTER";

        //switch (Season.valueOf(colObject))  // following line achieves same thing
        switch (Enum.valueOf(Season.class, season)) // any other difference between both approach
        {
            case WINTER: {
                System.out.println("Got it in switch case= VENDOR");
                break;
            }
            default:
                System.out.println("Fell thru.");
                break;
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: This discussion is useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163076/how-is-values-implemented-for-java-6-enums

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason the `Enum.valueof()` method is included is that it works with any `enum`.  By contrast, the `enum` `valueof` method for a specific method only works for that specific `enum` ... since `enum` classes cannot be used polymorphically.

Obviously the `Enum.valueOf(...)` method is only really useful if you are implementing code that *needs* to work for multiple `enum` types ... and generics don't cut it.

Answer (score 2):

`Enum.valueOf(Class<T>, String)` is used to *implement* the `valueOf(String)` method generated into each specific enum class.

Answer (score 1):

The method inside Enum is generic and can be used with any enum and the method inside enum is specific to that enum only.

Comment: why does Enum have .isdefined, but enum does not (i konw enum allows the setting of enumerations) what is Enum??