# Langton's Ant Algorithm

Tags: java

The problem of [Langton's Ant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langton%27s_ant) is simple. An ant walks a board with white and black squares.

- At a white square, turn 90° right, flip the color of the square, move forward one unit
- At a black square, turn 90° left, flip the color of the square, move forward one unit

When the "game" starts the board is all white.

I have implemented the simulation but has a really ugly solution for walkning and turning that I need help improving. Right now the walk is as follows:

```
if (dir == "NORTH") {
    // Walk up
} else if (dir == "EAST") {
    // Walk right
} else if (dir == "SOUTH") {
    // Walk down
} else if (dir == "WEST") {
    // Walk left
}
```

And the function for changing direction:

```
private void turn(String leftOrRight){
    if(dir == "NORTH" && lor == "RIGHT" ){
        dir = "EAST";
    } else if (dir == "NORTH" && leftOrRight == "LEFT" ){
        dir = "WEST";
    } else if (dir == "EAST" && leftOrRight == "RIGHT" ){
        dir = "SOUTH";
    } else if (dir == "EAST" && leftOrRight == "LEFT" ){
        dir = "NORTH";
    } else if (dir == "SOUTH" && leftOrRight == "RIGHT" ){
        dir = "WEST";
    } else if (dir == "SOUTH" && leftOrRight == "LEFT" ){
        dir = "EAST";
    } else if (dir == "WEST" && leftOrRight == "RIGHT" ){
        dir = "NORTH";
    } else if (dir == "WEST" && leftOrRight == "LEFT" ){
        dir = "SOUTH";
    }
}
```

I have thought about using ints instead of strings, but not quite sure how i should do it. Any help or hints is appreciated.

---

EDIT: Now I have changed some. I Created an Ant class that has variables

```
int x, int y, Direction dir
```

And run it with the following method:

```
private void runAnt(Ant ant) {
    int x = ant.getX();
    int y = ant.getY();

    // Check rule 1
    if (matrix[x][y] == true) {
        matrix[x][y] = false;
        w.setDot(x, y, Color.WHITE);
        ant.setDirection(ant.getDirection().right());

    // Check rule 2
    } else if (matrix[x][y] == false) {
        matrix[x][y] = true;
        w.setDot(x, y, Color.BLACK);
        ant.setDirection(ant.getDirection().left());
    }

    // Moves one unit forward according to direction.
    if (ant.getDirection().equals(Direction.N)) {
        ant.setY((ant.getY() - 1 + wSize) % wSize);

    } else if (ant.getDirection().equals(Direction.E)) {
        ant.setX((ant.getX() + 1) % wSize);

    } else if (ant.getDirection().equals(Direction.S)) {
        ant.setY((ant.getY() + 1) % wSize);

    } else if (ant.getDirection().equals(Direction.W)) {
        ant.setX((ant.getX() - 1 + wSize) % wSize);
    }
}
```

And my very first enum:

```
public static enum Direction {
    N, E, S, W;
    private static Direction[] vals = values();

    public Direction right() {
        return vals[(this.ordinal() + 1) % vals.length];
    }

    public Direction left() {
        return vals[(this.ordinal() + vals.length - 1) % vals.length];
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read this carefully: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: Also try using a boolean `isMovingLeft`.  It'll make toggling easier.

Comment: Use `enum` or constants, using tons of similar literals is scary & error prone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Combine using an enum with `next()` and `prev()` functions as explained [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17006263/18157).  Then a right turn is just a `next()` call and a left turn is a `prev()` call.

Comment: +1, I was just writing the same answer! Would probably rename `next()` and `prev()` to `left()` and `right()` though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried using your example. Can you check my update and see if i'm on the right track?

Comment: Looks good to me. You correctly handled the index going negative :-)

Answer (score 3):

You aren't going to get the results you expect when you use `==` to compare `String`s in Java.  Use the [`equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method instead.

I'd consider defining an [enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) for `NORTH`, `SOUTH`, `EAST`, and `WEST`.

Comment: Check my update. Is this what you meant? Is there other things that can be done in a smarter way?

Comment: @Goatcat I haven't tried running it, but that definitely looks much better.

Answer (score 2):

Assign an int to each direction(go clockwise):

```
NORTH = 0;
EAST = 1;
SOUTH = 2;
WEST = 3;
```

Assign left as -1; right as 1:

```
LEFT = -1;
RIGHT = 1;
```

Then you can have a simple function to change directions:

```
private void turn(int leftOrRight){
    dir = (dir + leftOrRight) % 4;
}
```

This is assuming you don't want to use `enums`, for whatever reason.

Comment: Isn't this basically a bit mask?

Comment: Somewhat, but simpler to understand if you don't grok bitshifts.

Comment: Fair enough. Seems reasonable. I still think this is more elegant than an enum, but I guess it's less typical.

Comment: This is basically the same as @JimGarrison's answer, but less type-safe since it's using ints instead of an enum.

Comment: True, and I upvoted his. Judging from the use of literals in the OP, I assumed type safety wasn't a huge concern, and went with the simplest-to-understand answer.

Comment: @Geobits - I think the only reason type safety doesn't seem like a big concern in the OP's code is because he doesn't know any better.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using an [enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) instead of string literals for `NORTH`, `SOUTH`, etc.

Enumerations are type-safe, so the compiler will warn you if you accidentally type `SUOTH` instead of `SOUTH`. In addition, `enum` instances can be safely compared with `==` (barring some weird edge cases involving serialization). The way you're comparing strings with `==` instead of `equals` right now could cause some potential problems depending on where `dir` and `leftOrRight` come from. [Take a look at this answer for an explanation of `==` vs `equals` on strings.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/513839/1427124)

Strings, enums and ints are all supported in the [`switch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) construct, so you can also consider using that instead of the if/else branches to make the code a little cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

If your direction was stored as an dx,dy displacement such as {0, -1}
Then turning left and right is :

1. Swap dx <=> dy

followed by either of :

2a. dx=-dx, or

2b. dy=-dy

(left and right turns)

No case statements, so it's simple and efficient.  Simply x+=dx, y+=dy to move forwards - and use the swap/negate trick shown, to rotate.

Why needlessly overcomplicate things : /

Comment: I am happy that you found an efficient solution!

Answer (score 0):

I feel like there's an elegant solution to be had here by using bitmasking. If you do that, then all of your turn operations could be done with simple bit operations instead. There's a really great tutorial on using bitmasks here:
http://www.vipan.com/htdocs/bitwisehelp.html

For instance, if you represent your direction as a 4-bit number and turning as a simple boolean, then you could do this all in a single if/else statement:

```
if (leftOrRight == 0){
    //right shift one bit
}
else if (leftOrRight == 1){
    //left shift one bit
}
```

Alternately you could just have your left/right indicator be either 1 or -1 and just left shift by you indicator on every turn.

Comment: Java has no 4-bit numbers so shifting or actually rotating is is bit ugly. But it works fine when using a 32bit int: http://ideone.com/htgs2A (oops, rotation should be inverted at some point)

Answer (score 0):

I would use an enum. Such as:

```
enum Directions {
    NORTH, 
    SOUTH, 
    EAST, 
    WEST
}
```

If you use Java 6 you can also use switches with that.

Oh, and also, **never** compare `String` with `==`. Use `equals`. See reason [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus).