# How to call the next enumeration element inside a method?

Tags: java

folks... I have `enum Rotation` with only one method - `public Rotation next()`. When calling `rot.next()` will return the next enumeration element representing the next 90 degree clock-wise rotation after rot. If, for example, intially the position at `CW0` the next call of the method would return `CW90` and the next call would return `CW270`. I've already looked what was considered to be a **duplicate** but my case is different.  I'm really stuck in this method and cannot come up with any ideas. Please somebody help me with this. Could anyone put me on a track how to implement this method? I appreciate if anybody helps.

```
public enum Rotation{
  CW0, CW90, CW180, CW270;

  // Calling rot.next() will return the next enumeration element
  // representing the next 90 degree clock-wise rotation after rot.
  public Rotation next();
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure there *is* a duplicate of this, but it might take me a little while to find...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17006239/whats-the-best-way-to-implement-next-and-previous-on-an-enum-type

Comment: Your code won't compile since next should be explicitly declared as abstract. Also, each enum constant must override the next method if it is abstract.

Comment: In my opinion, Suresh Sajja's answer is a better duplicate as the one that is set now.