# Java get next Enum value or start from first

Tags: java

I have an enum in Java as following:

```
public enum Cars
{
   Sport,
   SUV,
   Coupe
}
```

And I need to get the next value of the enum. So, assuming I have a variable called *myCurrentCar*:

```
private Cars myCurrentCar = Cars.Sport;
```

I need to create a function that when called set the value of *myCurrentCar* to the next value in the enum. If the enum does not have anymore values, I should set the variable to the first value of the enum.
I started my implementation in this way:

```
public Cars GetNextCar(Cars e)
{
  switch(e)
  {
     case Sport:
       return SUV;
     case SUV:
       return Coupe;
     case Coupe:
       return Sport;
     default:
       throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
  }
}
```

Which is working but it's an **high maitenance** function because every time I modify the enum list I have to refactor the function.
Is there a way to split the enum into an array of strings, get the next value and transform the string value into the original enum? So in case I am at the end of the array I simply grab the first index

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17006263/4467208

Comment: I know that answer but I wanted a infinite solution capable to go back to the first item when reach the end of the array, so it's not a duplicate

Comment: The question that this was marked with also wants to loop back to the first index, so technically it is a duplicate. I think my answer is a bit easier to read though :p

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yeah sure, it goes like this

```
public Cars getNextCar(Cars e)
{
  int index = e.ordinal();
  int nextIndex = index + 1;
  Cars[] cars = Cars.values();
  nextIndex %= cars.length;
  return cars[nextIndex];
}
```

Comment: Wanted to write an answer like this myself. Well. This looks perfect :)

Comment: Perfect, super fast I have to wait to mark it correct because you were faster than StackOverflow timer!

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: I was using this for compass directions, instead of cars so I needed to go in reverse order. Best I could come up with was adding this after the following line    `Cars[] cars = Cars.values();`
`if (previousIndex <0) {previousIndex = cars.length-1;}`