# using enum (as type) in generic class and looping through its elements

Tags: java, generics, enums

I have a generic class with enum type as generic, and I want to iterate through all elements in the enum. Hope the following example (not working) will make more clear what I want. What is the correct syntax?

```
public class GenericClass<T extends Enum<T>>{

    T myEnum;

    public void doSomething(){
        for(T element : myEnum.values()){// <-- values() not available
            ....
        }
    }
}
```

I would use the class this way

```
GenericClass<OtherClass.MyEnumType> manager;
manager.doSomething();
```

Comment: @ohlmar yes, it doesn't work that way. I can't see values().

Comment: Explain, why you want to use an `Enum` instead of maybe just a `List`? Give some more information about what you want to achieve! Since `Enum<T>` is not an array, `myEnum` is also no array and you can't loop over one `Enum` value!

Comment: You can't see `values()` because class `Enum` is not the same as an  `enum` (as opposed to `class`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're attempting to hold a reference to an *instance* of an enum which isn't very useful, but you can require that the enum class is passed to the constructor (called a *type token*).

With a class, you can use the (typed) class method [`getEnumConstants()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getEnumConstants%28%29) (which returns `null` if the class isn't an enum class, but we've bound it to be an enum class).

This compiles:

```
public class GenericClass<T extends Enum<T>> {

    Class<T> enumClass;

    public GenericClass(Class<T> enumClass) {
        this.enumClass = enumClass;
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        for (T element : enumClass.getEnumConstants()) {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not really possible. `values()` method is not part of the `Enum` class but of a class derived by the compiler from your enum: `public class YourEnum extends Enum<YourEnum>`.

See this SO question for more info: [How is values() implemented for Java 6 enums?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163076/how-is-values-implemented-for-java-6-enums)

Answer (score 1):

this is equivalent to the static `values()` method:

```
T[] items = myEnum.getDeclaringClass().getEnumConstants();
```

See [`Enum.getDeclaringClass()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#getDeclaringClass%28%29)

(Basically this returns the class defining the enum item, which may or may not be == myEnum.getClass(), depending on whether or not the enum item has a body)