# Order of list's elements

Tags: java, enums

Consider the following enum:

```
public enum Type{
     INTEGER,
     DOUBLE,
     BOOLEAN
}
```

Now, I have the following line:

```
List<Type> types = Arrays.asList(Type.values());
```

Do the list contains the elements in the same order they put into the enum? Is this order reliable?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. The [Java Language Specification for Enums](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.1) states:

```
/**
* Returns an array containing the constants of this enum 
* type, in the order they're declared.  This method may be
* used to iterate over the constants as follows:
*
*    for(E c : E.values())
*        System.out.println(c);
*
* @return an array containing the constants of this enum 
* type, in the order they're declared
*/
public static E[] values();
```

It will returned an array with the constants as they are declared.

Regarding the [`Arrays.asList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-) method, you can rely on its order as well:

> Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array. (Changes to the returned list "write through" to the array.)

Consider the below example, which is a very common way to initialize a `List`:

```
List<String> stooges = Arrays.asList("Larry", "Moe", "Curly");
```

The order of the list will be the same as in the array.

Comment: So, yeah it's clear that the array's order will be consistent with the enum's one. But what about `Arrays.asList()` method? Is it specified that the method doesn't chahnge the order?

Comment: So, I didn't find the order of the list returned by Arrays.asList is reliable. [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) I guess, if we need reliable order we'll have to construct a list on our own...

Comment: The order of `asList()` is predictable, I have clarified this in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The JLS mentions that `values()` *"Returns an array containing the constants of this enum type, in the order they're declared."* (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9). So yes, you can assume that the order will be the same as long as your enum type doesn't change

For some details see [How is values() implemented for Java 6 enums?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163076/how-is-values-implemented-for-java-6-enums)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain Order of Elements use `LinkedList`: -

`List<Type> types = new LinkedList<Type>(Arrays.asList(Type.values()));`

Comment: I need to maintain the same order as they were put into the enum.

Comment: I mean reliable order

Comment: Yeah , order will be maintained by `LinkedList`but what do you mean by *reliable*

Comment: It is true that a `LinkedList` is ordered, but so is any `List`. This will maintain the order, but why first create a `List`, then create a `LinkedList`?